# How to remove only one element from array in multiple duplicates in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing code for add and remove array in php. The arrays are pushing succesfully according to my requirement. Now I want to remove the array element. But Here is the condition. I have duplicate values in this array. So I just want to remove only one element of duplicate values not all

Here is the code

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_POST['value'];

$_SESSION['id'] = $id ;

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $id);


echo true;



?>
```

Here is the array I am getting

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 6 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 2 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 5 [13] => 1 [14] => 1 )
```

For example. I have multiple elements of 0 in this array. So I want to remove only one element not all.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to make it manually or automatically?

Comment: automatically @MrProPop

Comment: You want to remove only one element from those which have same value, but which one? You should tell us that, but also you should try to do it yourself first instead of asking us to do it for you. There are tons of easy docs on the web about php arrays

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: I try before upload that please provide me that doc if you have that ..  and in my question everything is clearly mention @Kaddath

Comment: use array_unique

Comment: @azadchouhan which duplicate value do you want removed?

Comment: "0" check my array in question please. Just one value not all...

Comment: if you say all is clear, that's fine for you, but i still see 6 rows with the value `0` in your array, and still nothing to tell me which ones i have to keep or remove.. whatever, other people will help you

Comment: well I am sorry for that if I am not able to clear my question. any 0 in the array can be removed. if it is 6 then I want to make 5 a and if it 5 then I want to make it 4.. I hope it is clear now @Kaddath

Comment: This array is creating dynamically. so I donot have idea where these values will be index in array that is my concern @Kaddath

Comment: ok, see Momo Kebab's edited answer, it should work allright for what you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove one instance of an ID from `$_SESSION['cart']`, you can use `array_search` to look for the posted value in that array and return its key if it's found.

```
$key = array_search($_POST['value'], $_SESSION['cart']);
```

`array_search` will return the *first* matching key, (so the key for just one item).

If a key is found, unset that key, and you'll remove only one of the corresponding value.

```
if ($key !== false) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
```

Comment: Thank you its working. This is what I am looking for

Comment: You're welcome. The answer by @Martijn does contain some good advice, though, if this is for a sort of shopping cart app. Using the item id as the key may be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$newarray = array();
$alreadydeleted = array();
foreach ($oldarray AS $key => $value)
{
    if (!in_array($value, $newarray) || in_array($value, $alreadydeleted))
        $newarray[$key] = $value;
    else
        $alreadydeleted[$key] = $value;
}
```

And you should have your new array with one duplicate removed

Comment: I want to remove one value from the array how can I do that? For example In my array you see there are multiple 0 values. and I want to remove only one

Comment: I edited the answer this should remove only one duplicate

Comment: A `foreach` and two `in_array` make this a costly operation :)

Comment: @Martijn if he wants to remove one duplicate for each value, he will need a loop even with Don't Panic's solution. Not saying this answer is better, but you're not right if you think `array_search` is less costly than `in_array`. By the way, if he doesn't want to remove all duplicates, Don't Panic's solution would also need to track elements removed in some way or another

Comment: It still is constly. But that is because of the structure of his data, it's not really doable in an efficient way

Answer (score 1):

**You should not continue as you are, but take time to reformat**. You are a cart, this can be done easier and more future-proof. When this project increases in size and complexity, *this will come back to haunt you* (building 5 [small] shops taught me this).

Instead of adding a *value* which is the ID of a product, add a *key* which is the ID of the product, with an array of information about it, like quantity.

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();

// to add a product:
$_SESSION['cart'][ $product_id ] = array('quantity'=>5);

// To remove from your array:
unset($_SESSION['cart'][ $product_id ]);

// To change the amount
$_SESSION['cart'][ $product_id ]['quantity'] = $newValue;
// Or, alternatively:
$_SESSION['cart'][ $product_id ]['quantity'] += 1; // add one.
```

Comment: I agree with this approach in general, but I think the OP is asking about reducing the quantity of one item by one, not removing the item altogether.

Comment: Added that demo as well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_POST['value'];

$_SESSION['id'] = $id ;

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

//You can try this
if(!array_search($id,$_SESSION['cart'],TRUE))
{
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $id);
}

//OR can do this after array_push
$new_unique_array = array_unique($_SESSION['cart']);


echo true;



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($key = array_search(0, $array)) !== false) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

So first occurring value 0 will delete . Try this